# Changing Jumbotron Image

Tags: css, django

Setup:

Product -> src -> static -> ostatic [ contains two folders css and images ] -> images -> this contains all my images.

Using bootstrap and trying to add background-image: to jumbotron, having spent two hours now it's really bothering me. Within django I can just call                       {% static 'images/imagename.jpg' %}" and it'll work fine, but when trying to do i.e. background-image: url('images/imagename.jpg'); this will not work and I've tried many other combinations too, including reading a lot of stackoverflow questions on topic..none of the solutions have seemed to help me though =/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the path relative to the site root. Based on the structure you tell us:

```
background-image: url('/src/static/ostatic/images/imagename.jpg');
```

The leading `/` should start the path at the site root.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/`?

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work :( this is becoming more of a problem than it should be!

Comment: @LarsW - you're right, that'll teach me to not double check my answers - user2982832 - try again without the dot

Comment: @Starscream1984 Still not recognising it =/ urgh :( thank you for attempting to help though!

Comment: Not found: /src/static/ostatic/images/imagename.jpg 404 2177 error according to the server

Comment: Then I think the path is not right - I'm not sure what the working folder structure of your site is.... maybe experiment removing sections of the path from the left hand side and re-trying e.g. '/static/ostatic/images/imagename.jpg' then '/ostatic/images/imagename.jpg' etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

it looks like you can't use a local picture there and that it must be a link

I mean something like this:

```
background-image : url(https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/bight-orange-colored-light-bulb_23-2148182084.jpg);
```

*not that specific link tho ^_^*